# Creating/Edit Users using Force.com License

Tags: force.com, administration

I'm building an app on Force.com platform and the users would be having a force.com license.

Does the admin need to have a full salesforce license to create users or i can create users even if the admin has a force.com license.

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

The admin needs a full Salesforce licence, you simply cannot give a Force.com user a 'System Administrator' profile.